# What to do after forgetting to perform Sajda as-Suhw?

Tags: salat, sunni, mistake

I mistakenly recited [Tashahhud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tashahhud) in the first Raka' and then I did in the second one, too. I remembered that I have to perform Sajda as-Sahw but in the end I forgot and I continued with rest of my prayers. What should I do now?

Comment: You can either repeat the prayer (if time is left) or do this sujud at the end of your next fard prayer with a correct intention.

Comment: Of course you could also perform the sujud once you recalled you've missed it. Some madhabs would reject or insist on one of these options